# Comparing two algorithims with the BigO notation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to figure out which of these 2 algorithms is the slowest and what impact does the size of n have.

The algorithms are:

6n^2 + 9

n^2 + 9n

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: From what I can figure out, both algortihims have a worst case scenario of O(n^2).

Comment: You can actually prove that both of them are of `O(n^2)`.

Comment: If both algortihims are O(n^2) then how can you tell which one is slower and do you know what their big O would be if n was small?

Comment: Just compare the functions. Find out for which `n` the first one takes more steps than the second one. You can see that the first one `always` takes slighly more steps to complete, despite both of them being of the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually prove that both of them are of `O(n²)`. Why is that?

- if `f(n) = 6n² + 9`, then:
- `O(f(n)) ∈ O(6n² + 9)`, then:
- `O(f(n)) ∈ 6 * O(n²) + 9 * O(1)`, then:
- `O(f(n)) ∈ O(n²)`

In a similar way you can prove that `g(n) = n² + 9n` is again of order `O(n²)`. You can additionally compare the functions to see for which `n` the second one takes more steps to complete and then you'll find out that the first one always takes *more*.

However, since both of them are of `O(n²)`, then you can assume that they are equally fast/slow, unless you find a function that is an upper bound for `g(n)` and lower bound for `f(n)`.

Comment: Just wanted to add more perspective to the problem: I'm a software engineer. As such, I'm really *only* interested in the functions being `O(n^2)` - the specifics of whether it's `6n^2 + 9` or `n^2 + 9n` are irrelevant. As far as I'm aware, that's basically the same in general. Unless there is some other analysis that computer scientists might be interested in. If there is a need to check which one is "better", as a software engineer I'd try to guestimate it. Assume `n=1` and solve. Repeat with `n=10`, `n=100`, `n=1000`. That should be enough for a finger in the air type of comparison.